# Java Why does my for loop set i to 0 after i is 4?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Ok, I'm trying to get the output to look a certain way. Print 10 numbers the new line. For some reason after running through loop 4 it sets i to 0. I'll put the file I'm reading from first. I eventually want to write it to a new file. This is for a class, just one assignment and I'm not asking you guys to do the assignment. (Basically I have to read the file and write to a new file with the name designated in the first file. And only use the number of numbers at the top of the first file.

The txt file contents:

```
MyOutput.txt 23 
20 1 4 5 7 
45
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 77 88 99 23 34 
56 66 77 88 99 100 110 120
```

and the code
...

```
package reading_with_exceptions;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inputFilename {


    static Scanner kbInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String lines = null;
        Scanner inFile = null;
        int count = 0;
        boolean metCount = false;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("src/MyInput.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        lines = inFile.nextLine();
        lines.trim();

        //Now check to see if line is empty
        //If not empty get the ouput file name and number of lines from file
        if(lines.length()>0) {        
            String outPutFile = lines.substring(0, lines.indexOf(' '));
            String numNumbers = lines.substring((lines.indexOf(' ')+1), (lines.length()-1));
            numNumbers.trim();
            count = Integer.parseInt(numNumbers);
            System.out.print(outPutFile+"  ");
            System.out.println(count);
        }

        //


        //check if there is another line in the file
        int i=0;
        while(inFile.hasNextLine() && !metCount) {

            lines = inFile.nextLine();
            String[] separated = lines.split(" ");

            for( i = 0; i<separated.length; i++) {

                System.out.print(separated[i]+"  ");

                if((i+1) % 10 ==0) {
                    System.out.println("...");
                }
                //System.out.print("  spot:"+i+" ");
                //System.out.println("i:" +i  +"count:"+count);
                if(i>=count)
                    metCount = true;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

...

I've tried stepping though it in Eclipse and still can't resolve the problem. It only happens every other time. First count goes to 4 Second count goes to 10 Third goes to 4 etc.

Comment: You reset `i` to `0` on every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're first line of output outputs the `count` as `23`.

The processing stops because you're using the line count as a comparator with your string token count...

Hence the metCount gets set to `true` in the while loop and the program ends

I've edited the code with some improvements so you can understand this more clearly...

I've extracted some parts to methods so you can have a named method rather than needing comments.

```
package reading_with_exceptions;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inputFilename {

    static Scanner kbInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inFile = open("src/MyInput.txt");

        /**
         * First check you have a first line.
         */
        if (!inFile.hasNext()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("File is empty");
        }
        String header = inFile.nextLine().trim();

        /**
         * Check first line is not blank
         */
        if(isBlank(header)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("First line has no content");
        }

        /**
         * Get filename and total line count from file
         */
        String filename = getFilename(header);
        int totalLines = getNumberOfLines(header);

        /**
         * output results to console on one line
         */
        System.out.println(filename + "  " + totalLines);

        /**
         * iterate over/process the lines one by one (but not the last line)
         * This whole process could be put in a method named processLines(...) with relevant arguments passed.
         * The more you nest your code, the harder it becomes to read/debug... and the easier it is for bugs to hide.
         * The more your variables have meaningless names (i, j, k) the harder it is to follow.
         * Tip: try to use methods and work on small bits of code at a time... much easier to read and understand a
         * single, well named function with less steps to it than one large function.
         */
        boolean isLastLine = false;

        while(inFile.hasNextLine() && !isLastLine) {

            String[] separated = inFile.nextLine().split(" ");

            for(int tokenCount = 0; tokenCount < separated.length; tokenCount++) {
                /**
                 * print out the token
                 */
                System.out.print(separated[tokenCount]+"  ");

                /**
                 * continue on a new line after every 10th token is printed to the console
                 */
                newLineAfterTenthTokenInASingleLine(tokenCount);

                /**
                 * here when `tokenCount` passes over the 23rd item (`separated[tokenCount]`),
                 * `metCount` is set to `true` and the program ends.
                 * This is probably not what's wanted as you want to compare a `lineCount` to the `totalLines`, not the `tokenCount`
                 */
                if(tokenCount>=totalLines) { // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE'S THE PROBLEM
                    isLastLine = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void newLineAfterTenthTokenInASingleLine(int tokenId) {
        if((tokenId+1) % 10 == 0) {
            continueOnNewLine();
        }
    }

    private static boolean isBlank(String firstLine) {
        return firstLine.length()==0;
    }

    private static Scanner open(String inFile) {
        try {
            return new Scanner(new FileReader(inFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new
        }
    }

    private static void continueOnNewLine() {
        System.out.println("...");
    }

    private static int getNumberOfLines(String header) {
        int beginIndex = header.indexOf(' ') + 1;
        int endIndex = header.length() - 1;
        return Integer.parseInt(header.substring(beginIndex, endIndex).trim());
    }

    private static String getFilename(String header) {
        int beginIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = header.indexOf(' ');
        return header.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }
}
```